# Generate a histogram with counting in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

I have to make a mass histogram of animals with a dataframe on pandas. The goal is that on my x-axis, I have the different masses of my CSV file, and on my y-axis, I have the number of animals that have that mass. I am a beginner in this field and I need to make a simple and understandable code

Here is my current code :

`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv("S:\Annee1\ISD\TP3\PanTHERIA_1-0_WR05_Aug2008.txt", sep='\t')

ax = (df
      .loc[:, ['5-1_AdultBodyMass_g', 'MSW05_Binomial']]
      .groupby('MSW05_Binomial')
      .count('MSW05_Binomial')
      .plot.bar(rot=45, figsize=(16, 8))
      )
ax.set_title('Masses corporelles de tous les animaux', fontsize=14)
ax.set_xlabel('Animaux', fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel('Masse corporelle', fontsize=12)
```

`

[image: CSV File]

Thanks a lot

PS: If you have any questions about my project, don't hesitate

Comment: hi, can you add a minimal reproductible example of your dataframe pls ?

Comment: Yes, I edited my question. All the rows with -999 value is deleted with my filter. The CSV file is awful I know but it's not mine

Comment: minimal reproductible example means something we can reproduce in our code, example : data = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3},
        {'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30}]

Comment: If you want I've the file .txt to download, it's easier : https://github.com/pedroj/Megafauna/blob/master/datasets/PanTHERIA_1-0_WR05_Aug2008.txt

Comment: Did you try Seaborn? E.g. `ax = sns.countplot(data=df, x='5-1_AdultBodyMass_g', y='MSW05_Binomial')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use directly the `pandas.DataFrame.hist` function.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("S:\Annee1\ISD\TP3\PanTHERIA_1-0_WR05_Aug2008.txt", sep="\t")

ax = plt.axes()
mass_column = "5-1_AdultBodyMass_g"
df[(df[mass_column] < 1e4) & (df[mass_column] > 0)].hist(column=mass_column, bins=100, ax=ax)
ax.set_title("Masses corporelles de tous les animaux", fontsize=14)
ax.set_xlabel("Masse corporelle (g)", fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel("Nombre d'animaux", fontsize=12)
```

Answer (score 0):

Histogram allows us to group data into bins and plot how many values (count) or frequency of values (density) fall into those bins. Meanwhile,

1. Not sure your dataframe is clearl enough especially for the types/number of animals you which to make a mass histogram
2. It depends on the range of masses you want on your x-axis, to make bins
3. You can use matplotlib.pyplot.hist() method to make a histogram visualization as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# select the data
mass = df["5-1_AdultBodyMass_g"]

# make bins
# for instance:
bins = [500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000]

# or 

bins = np.arange(0,100000,10000)

# make a plot
plt.hist(mass,bins=bins)
plt.title("Masses corporelles de tous les animaux")
plt.xlabel("Masses d'animaux")
plt.ylabel("Compter")
plt.show();
```